# JSON Data format

Tags: java, json, rest, datetime, jackson

Ola pessoal eu tenho um webservice que deve buscar algumas infromacoes no banco de dados e retornar um objeto json e estou com problemas com relaçao a data.

aqui é o objeto

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;


@XmlRootElement
public class Carro{

    @XmlElement
    private String id;

    @XmlElement
    private String nome;

    @XmlElement
    private Timestamp dtFabricacao;
... gets and setters
```

}

eu vou até o banco de dados e preencho as propriedades da classe normalmente a data fica "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss z"

porem o json fica com assim

```
{
"id": 1
"nome": "Fiesta"
"dtFabricacao": 152679516567919
}
```

ja tentei criar uma classe de serializacao e anotations e nada funciona já nao sei mais o que fazer.

estou usando jax e jackson para converter o objeto para json e meu projeto utiliza maven

Answer (score 2):

Este é o formato da data em Json, caso você esteja utilizando javascript para consumir este serviço você pode utilizar a data desta forma:

```
var date = new Date(152679516567919);
alert(date);
```

Caso queira formatar de outra maneira você pode utilizar este bom plugin:

```
$.format.date(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss');
```

https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat

Caso queira enviar no formato que você vê no banco de dados, crie uma outra propriedade porém como string tipo este código e já preencha com o valor formatado:

```
@XmlElement
private String dtFabricacao;
```

Comment: Muito boa, resposta perfeita e completamente util